How to solve NextJs Not Found error for api routes?
I have an api route api/notifications/route.ts
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { v4 } from 'uuid';

import { pusherServer } from '@/lib/pusher';
import { notificationSchema, notificationSchemaType } from '@/lib/schemas';
import { createSupabaseServerClient } from '@/lib/supabase/server-clients';

// those notifications that will only be shown to the team heads
export async function POST(req: Request) {
  const serverSupabase = createSupabaseServerClient();

  const body = await req.json(); //request will contain the text

  const dataForParsing = {
    text: body.text,
    created_at: new Date().toISOString(),
    notf_id: v4(),
  };

  //Parse the body
  let notificationData: notificationSchemaType | undefined = undefined;
  const validationData = notificationSchema.safeParse(dataForParsing);

  if (validationData.success) {
    notificationData = validationData.data;
  } else {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: validationData.error }, { status: 400 });
  }

  //Check if the notificationData exists
  if (!notificationData || notificationData === undefined) {
    console.log('Notification data does not exist')
    return NextResponse.json(
      { success: false, error: 'Something went wrong' },
      {
        status: 400,
      }
    );
  }

  //Insert the notification
  const { error } = await serverSupabase
    .from('notifications')
    .insert([notificationData]);

  if (error) {
    console.log(error.message)
    return NextResponse.json(
      {
        success: false,
        error: error.message,
        message: 'Notification not inserted in the database',
      },
      {
        status: 500,
      }
    );
  }

  console.log('inserted')

  pusherServer.trigger('bell-dot', 'pink-dot', {});
  pusherServer.trigger(
    'notification',
    'new-notification',
    notificationData as notificationSchemaType
  );

  return NextResponse.json({ success: true }, { status: 201 });
}

This is where I am calling the api
export default function RegisterMemberForm({ user }: RegisterMemberFormProps) {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const form = useForm<memberFormSchemaType>({
    resolver: zodResolver(memberFormSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      name: user.name as string,
      email: user.email as string,
    },
  });

  async function registerMember(formData: memberFormSchemaType) {
    const response = await fetch('/api/member', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(formData),
    });
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error('Failed to add department');
    }

    return response.json();
  }

  async function addNotification(notificationText: string) {
    const response = await fetch('api/notifications',{
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({text: 'A new member was just registered!'}),
    })
    if(response.status !== 201){
      throw new Error('Failed to add notification');
    }
  }

  const { mutate: notificationMutate } = useMutation({
    mutationFn: addNotification,
    onError: () => {console.log('got error from notification api')}
    //even if the notification is not successful, we don't want the registeration to fail
  });

  const { mutate } = useMutation({
    mutationFn: registerMember,
    onSuccess: () => {
      notificationMutate('A new employee was just registered!');
      toast.success('Registeration Successful');
      setIsLoading(false);
    },
    onError: () => {
      setIsLoading(false);
      toast.error('Failed to register');
    },
  });

  async function onSubmit(formData: memberFormSchemaType) {
    setIsLoading(true);
    mutate(formData);
    // router.push(`/${splitPath[1]}`);
  }

  async function handleTest(){
    const response = await fetch('/api/testt',{
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    
    });
    if(response.ok){
      console.log('success');
    }else{
      console.log('failed');
    }
  }

  return (
    <Form {...form}>
      <form
        onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
        className='mx-auto grid w-full max-w-md gap-6'
      >
     {/* Code for the form  */}

        <div className='flex justify-end'>
          <Button type='submit' disabled={isLoading} size='sm'>
            {isLoading && (
              <Icons.spinner
                className='mr-2 size-4 animate-spin'
                aria-hidden='true'
              />
            )}
            Register Me
            <span className='sr-only'>Register Me</span>
          </Button>
        </div>
      </form>
      <button onClick={handleTest}> Test </button>
    </Form>
  );
}

The flow of the application is that  the user will click a button Register Me to register themselves as a member on the website. This will call an api that will first register the user. If the registeration is successful, the api for the notifications will be called to perform the necessary tasks.
When I run the notifications api through the thunder client, everything works perfectly well, the database is also updated, the browser also shows the desired results, I also get the console statements in the terminal.
But when I click the button that is supposed to make the call for the api by going through the desired flow of the application, I get error 404 and the following Response.  (The member is registered successfully but the notification is not added to the database.)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html id="__next_error__">
    <head>
        <meta charSet="utf-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <link rel="preload" as="script" fetchPriority="low" href="/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js"/>
        <script src="/_next/static/chunks/main-app.js" async=""></script>
        <script src="/_next/static/chunks/app-pages-internals.js" async=""></script>
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex"/>
        <meta name="next-error" content="not-found"/>
        <title>Not Found</title>
        <script src="/_next/static/chunks/polyfills.js" noModule=""></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="/_next/static/chunks/webpack.js" async=""></script>
        <script>
            (self.__next_f = self.__next_f || []).push([0]);
            self.__next_f.push([2, null])
        </script>
        <script>
            self.__next_f.push([1, "1:HL[\"/_next/static/css/app/layout.css?v=1712396107851\",\"style\"]\n0:\"$L2\"\n"])
        </script>
        <script>
            self.__next_f.push([1, "3:I[\"(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.1.3_@babel+core@7.22.9_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js\",[\"app-pages-internals\",\"static/chunks/app-pages-internals.js\"],\"\"]\n6:I[\"(app-pages-browser)/./src/components/react-query-provider.tsx\",[\"app/layout\",\"static/chunks/app/layout.js\"],\"\"]\n7:I[\"(app-pages-browser)/./src/components/theme-provider.tsx\",[\"app/layout\",\"static/chunks/app/layout.js\"],\"ThemeProvider\"]\n8:I[\"(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/."])
        </script>
        <script>
            self.__next_f.push([1, "pnpm/next@14.1.3_@babel+core@7.22.9_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/client/components/layout-router.js\",[\"app-pages-internals\",\"static/chunks/app-pages-internals.js\"],\"\"]\n9:I[\"(app-pages-browser)/./src/app/error.tsx\",[\"app/error\",\"static/chunks/app/error.js\"],\"\"]\na:I[\"(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.1.3_@babel+core@7.22.9_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/client/components/render-from-template-context.js\",[\"app-pages-internals\",\"static/chunks/app-page"])
        </script>
        <script>
            self.__next_f.push([1, "s-internals.js\"],\"\"]\nb:I[\"(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/.pnpm/react-hot-toast@2.4.1_csstype@3.1.3_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/react-hot-toast/dist/index.mjs\",[\"app/layout\",\"static/chunks/app/layout.js\"],\"Toaster\"]\nd:I[\"(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.1.3_@babel+core@7.22.9_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js\",[\"app-pages-internals\",\"static/chunks/app-pages-internals.js\"],\"\"]\ne:[\"children\"]\n"])
        </script>
        <script>
            self.__next_f.push([1, "2:[[[\"$\",\"link\",\"0\",{\"rel\":\"stylesheet\",\"href\":\"/_next/static/css/app/layout.css?v=1712396107851\",\"precedence\":\"next_static/css/app/layout.css\",\"crossOrigin\":\"$undefined\"}]],[\"$\",\"$L3\",null,{\"buildId\":\"development\",\"assetPrefix\":\"\",\"initialCanonicalUrl\":\"/Amama%20Fatima/api/notifications\",\"initialTree\":[\"\",{\"children\":[\"__DEFAULT__\",{}]},\"$undefined\",\"$undefined\",true],\"initialSeedData\":[\"\",{\"children\":[\"__DEFAULT__\",{},[\"$L4\",\"$L5\",null]]},[null,[\"$\",\"html\",null,{\"children\":[[\"$\",\"head\",null,{}],[\"$\",\"body\",null,{\"className\":\"min-h-screen bg-background font-sans antialiased\",\"children\":[\"$\",\"$L6\",null,{\"children\":[\"$\",\"$L7\",null,{\"attribute\":\"class\",\"defaultTheme\":\"system\",\"enableSystem\":true,\"children\":[[\"$\",\"$L8\",null,{\"parallelRouterKey\":\"children\",\"segmentPath\":[\"children\"],\"loading\":\"$undefined\",\"loadingStyles\":\"$undefined\",\"loadingScripts\":\"$undefined\",\"hasLoading\":false,\"error\":\"$9\",\"errorStyles\":[],\"errorScripts\":[],\"template\":[\"$\",\"$La\",null,{}],\"templateStyles\":\"$undefined\",\"templateScripts\":\"$undefined\",\"notFound\":[\"$\",\"main\",null,{\"children\":[\"$\",\"section\",null,{\"className\":\"bg-white\",\"children\":[\"$\",\"div\",null,{\"className\":\"layout flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-center text-center text-black\",\"children\":[[\"$\",\"svg\",null,{\"stroke\":\"currentColor\",\"fill\":\"currentColor\",\"strokeWidth\":\"0\",\"viewBox\":\"0 0 24 24\",\"className\":\"drop-shadow-glow animate-flicker text-red-500\",\"children\":[\"$undefined\",[[\"$\",\"path\",\"0\",{\"d\":\"M4.00098 20V14C4.00098 9.58172 7.5827 6 12.001 6C16.4193 6 20.001 9.58172 20.001 14V20H21.001V22H3.00098V20H4.00098ZM6.00098 14H8.00098C8.00098 11.7909 9.79184 10 12.001 10V8C8.68727 8 6.00098 10.6863 6.00098 14ZM11.001 2H13.001V5H11.001V2ZM19.7792 4.80761L21.1934 6.22183L19.0721 8.34315L17.6578 6.92893L19.7792 4.80761ZM2.80859 6.22183L4.22281 4.80761L6.34413 6.92893L4.92991 8.34315L2.80859 6.22183Z\",\"children\":\"$undefined\"}]]],\"style\":{\"color\":\"$undefined\"},\"height\":60,\"width\":60,\"xmlns\":\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\"}],[\"$\",\"h1\",null,{\"className\":\"mt-8 text-4xl md:text-6xl\",\"children\":\"Page Not Found\"}],[\"$\",\"a\",null,{\"href\":\"/\",\"children\":\"Back to home\"}]]}]}]}],\"notFoundStyles\":[],\"styles\":null}],[\"$\",\"$Lb\",null,{\"position\":\"bottom-center\",\"reverseOrder\":false,\"gutter\":8,\"toastOptions\":{\"duration\":3000,\"style\":{\"background\":\"hsl(var(--background))\",\"color\":\"hsl(var(--foreground))\",\"border\":\"1px solid hsl(var(--border))\"}}}],[\"$\",\"div\",null,{\"className\":\"fixed bottom-1 left-1 z-50 flex size-6 items-center justify-center rounded-full bg-gray-800 p-3 font-mono text-xs text-white\",\"children\":[[\"$\",\"div\",null,{\"className\":\"block sm:hidden\",\"children\":\"xs\"}],[\"$\",\"div\",null,{\"className\":\"hidden sm:block md:hidden lg:hidden xl:hidden 2xl:hidden\",\"children\":\"sm\"}],[\"$\",\"div\",null,{\"className\":\"hidden md:block lg:hidden xl:hidden 2xl:hidden\",\"children\":\"md\"}],[\"$\",\"div\",null,{\"className\":\"hidden lg:block xl:hidden 2xl:hidden\",\"children\":\"lg\"}],[\"$\",\"div\",null,{\"className\":\"hidden xl:block 2xl:hidden\",\"children\":\"xl\"}],[\"$\",\"div\",null,{\"className\":\"hidden 2xl:block\",\"children\":\"2xl\"}]]}]]}]}]}]]}],null]],\"initialHead\":[[\"$\",\"meta\",null,{\"name\":\"robots\",\"content\":\"noindex\"}],\"$Lc\"],\"globalErrorComponent\":\"$d\",\"missingSlots\":\"$We\"}]]\n"])
        </script>
        <script>
            self.__next_f.push([1, "5:E{\"digest\":\"NEXT_NOT_FOUND\",\"message\":\"NEXT_NOT_FOUND\",\"stack\":\"Error: NEXT_NOT_FOUND\\n    at notFound (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.1.3_@babel+core@7.22.9_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/client/components/not-found.js:23:19)\\n    at ParallelRouteDefault (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.1.3_@babel+core@7.22.9_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/client/components/parallel-route-default.js:23:28)\\n    at ej (C:\\\\Users\\\\Noor Fatima\\\\Documents\\\\team-management\\\\node_modules\\\\.pnpm\\\\next@14.1.3_@babel+core@7.22.9_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0\\\\node_modules\\\\next\\\\dist\\\\compiled\\\\next-server\\\\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:264151)\\n    at C:\\\\Users\\\\Noor Fatima\\\\Documents\\\\team-management\\\\node_modules\\\\.pnpm\\\\next@14.1.3_@babel+core@7.22.9_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0\\\\node_modules\\\\next\\\\dist\\\\compiled\\\\next-server\\\\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:276953\\n    at Array.toJSON (C:\\\\Users\\\\Noor Fatima\\\\Documents\\\\team-management\\\\node_modules\\\\.pnpm\\\\next@14.1.3_@babel+core@7.22.9_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0\\\\node_modules\\\\next\\\\dist\\\\compiled\\\\next-server\\\\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:281723)\\n    at stringify (\u003canonymous\u003e)\\n    at C:\\\\Users\\\\Noor Fatima\\\\Documents\\\\team-management\\\\node_modules\\\\.pnpm\\\\next@14.1.3_@babel+core@7.22.9_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0\\\\node_modules\\\\next\\\\dist\\\\compiled\\\\next-server\\\\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:268079\\n    at ez (C:\\\\Users\\\\Noor Fatima\\\\Documents\\\\team-management\\\\node_modules\\\\.pnpm\\\\next@14.1.3_@babel+core@7.22.9_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0\\\\node_modules\\\\next\\\\dist\\\\compiled\\\\next-server\\\\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:268158)\\n    at eH (C:\\\\Users\\\\Noor Fatima\\\\Documents\\\\team-management\\\\node_modules\\\\.pnpm\\\\next@14.1.3_@babel+core@7.22.9_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0\\\\node_modules\\\\next\\\\dist\\\\compiled\\\\next-server\\\\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:268559)\\n    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\\\\Users\\\\Noor Fatima\\\\Documents\\\\team-management\\\\node_modules\\\\.pnpm\\\\next@14.1.3_@babel+core@7.22.9_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0\\\\node_modules\\\\next\\\\dist\\\\compiled\\\\next-server\\\\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:265057)\\n    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:573:17)\\n    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:514:7)\"}\n"])
        </script>
        <script>
            self.__next_f.push([1, "c:[[\"$\",\"meta\",\"0\",{\"name\":\"viewport\",\"content\":\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\"}],[\"$\",\"meta\",\"1\",{\"charSet\":\"utf-8\"}],[\"$\",\"title\",\"2\",{\"children\":\"Not Found\"}]]\n4:null\n"])
        </script>
        <script>
            self.__next_f.push([1, ""])
        </script>
    </body>
</html>




Second Image my vs code console when i call the api through the thunder client
Third Image my vs code console when i call the api by clicking the button on the local host
When I run the api from the thunder client I get the necessary console statements and the database is also updated. I even get compiling api/notifications But when I click the button on the website to call the api, I get compiling/not-found

Could you please share the console when you got this error?

I attached an image in my original question. I am getting the error in the response of my api. (in the inspect tab of the browser)

how abt the console tab? can you take the screenshot too?

Attached the console tab screen shots as well. When I run the api from the thunder client I get the necessary console statements and the database is also updated. I even get compiling api/notifications. But when I click the button on the website to call the api, I get compiling/not-found
